# ASP.NET Core 3.0 in endless redirection loop

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have recently upgraded an existing **ASP.NET Core** 2.2 web app to 3.0. Everything compiles. We use **Azure ADB2C** for authentication. Previously the user would be directed to the login page and upon entering their credentials they would be navigated to the Default page.

After upgrading to **ASP.NET Core** 3.0 however, after they have been directed to the login page the app goes into an infinite re-direction loop.

I can login correctly using an older version of the app (that still uses **ASP.NET Core** 2.2) so it's not the **Azure ADB2C** configuration. It must be some mis-configuration with the *routing* in the **ASP.NET Core** 3.0 app.

Here is my startup configuration.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddAzureAdB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options))

    //ensure the user must be authenticated before they can access any of the pages from the app
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => { options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/"); });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    { 
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();
}
```

Most of this code has remained unchanged and was working correctly when running under **ASP.NET Core** 2.2. Since I have upgraded to **ASP.NET Core** 3.0 it goes into an infinite re-direction loop.

I can't see what could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of your middleware is incorrect.`app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();` is required to be placed after `app.UseAuthentication();`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   //...
   app.UseAuthentication();
   app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```